# Routing multiple URLs to the same view in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, routes

I'm having some trouble trying to configure my ASP.NET MVC project to route multiple URLs to the same view.  Given the following URLs:

```
localhost:1234
localhost:1234/Products
localhost:1234/Products/1
localhost:1234/Products/abcd
localhost:1234/Products/whatever
```

I would like each of these to route the user to the same view (`Products.cshtml`, for instance).

Following an example on [this site](http://www.dotnet-stuff.com/tutorials/aspnet-mvc/understanding-url-rewriting-and-url-attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-mvc5-with-examples), I've decorated my Controller action with a special route attribute:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("Products/{id?}")]
public ActionResult Products(string id)
{
    return View();
}
```

And in my `RouteConfig.cs` file, I have my default route set up:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Products", action = "Products", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

The `localhost:1234` and the `localhost:1234/Products` links both work, but this isn't working for the remaining URLs.

Comment: Did you remember to call `MapMvcAttributeRoutes()` somewhere in your initialization code?

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen Oh god, no I didn't.  This solves half of the problem, but I call this function, the default link is no longer working.

Comment: You can just add another route `url: "Products/{id}",` (with the same defaults) before the default route and remove the `[Route("Products/{id?}")]` attribute

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen Ultimately, I got this working with your suggestion and with the inclusion of a new `routes.MapRoute` declaration with a blank URL parameter.  Could you post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attributes all look correct to me, so you probably just forgot to map the attribute routes. Remember to call `MapMvcAttributeRoutes()` somewhere in your initialization code.